# Android Wigdet Theme Change

Tags: android, kotlin, widget

How can I set the theme change in the widget when the theme change is made in my Android application?

I tried such a method, but I did not get any results.

```
 int themeMode = mContext.getSharedPreferences("DH_MODE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("DH_MODE", 0);

        switch (themeMode){
            case 0: {
                // Gündüz modu
                rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_flame, R.drawable.evening_logo);
                rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_title," Gündüz modu");
                rv.setTextColor(R.id.txt_title, Color.parseColor("#000000"));//siyah

                break;
            }
            case 1: {
                //Gece modu
                rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_flame, R.drawable.evening_logo); // logolar da değişecekse diye imageview i de ekledim
                rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_title," Gece modu");
                rv.setTextColor(R.id.txt_title, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));//beyaz
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                //Gün batımı modu
                rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_flame, R.drawable.evening_logo);
                rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_title," gün batımı modu ");
                rv.setTextColor(R.id.txt_title, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));//beyaz
                break;
            }
            case 3:{
                rv.setImageViewResource(R.id.img_flame, R.drawable.evening_logo);
                rv.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_title," akşam modu");
                rv.setTextColor(R.id.txt_title, Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));//beyaz
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, is it that it's not showing the right theme, or the theme is not changing at all, or something else? If you want it to change depending on the device's theme, I've got the code for that if you need it.

Comment: Thank you. I want it to change according to the theme of the application.

Comment: Okay, see my answer @Emine Akduman.

Comment: ok.it worked,thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked, can you accept my anwser @Emine Akduman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the widget when the theme in your app changes in your MainActivity or the activity the theme change gets notified in:

```
    val widgetManagerObj = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
    val appWidgetIdArr = widgetManagerObj.getAppWidgetIds(ComponentName(applicationContext, YourWidgetProvider::class.java))
    val refreshIntentObj = Intent(applicationContext, YourWidgetProvider::class.java)
    refreshIntentObj.action = STATUS_ACTION
    refreshIntentObj.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIdArr)
    sendBroadcast(refreshIntentObj)
```

And keep the code that you provided in your question the same. Tell me if it works :)